# How can I use a PHP regex to transform the contents of certain HTML tag attributes?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I think I am right in asuming that RegEx can do this job, I'm just not sure how I would do it!

Basically I have a number of links on my website that are in the format of:

```
<a href="EXAMPLE/Example.html">Example</a>
```

I need some code that will transform the href value so that it gets outputed in lowercase, but that does not affect the anchor text . E.g:

```
<a href="example/example.html">Example</a>
```

Is this possible? And if so, what would be the code to do this?

Comment: A regex can't do any transforming. It's a replace function which will do the transforming, regular expressions are only used to help find the right bits to transform

Comment: Remember: "example.com/EXAMPLE" is _not_ the same as "example.com/example". You are going to break the link.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML and transform it with regular expressions.  Use a dedicated HTML parser to do the work for you.  Look into DOMDocument.

Answer (score 2):

you can use preg_replace_callback

something like that

```
function replace($match){
    return strtolower($matches[0])
}

...
preg_replace_callback('/(href="[^"]*")/i' 'replace',$str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using preg_match and strtolower functions

```
preg_match('/\<a(.*)\>(.*)\<\/a\>/i',$cadena, $a);
$a[1]=strtolower($a[1]);
$cadena = preg_replace('/\<a(.*)\>(.*)\<\/a\>/i',$a[1],$cadena);
echo $cadena;
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks but that only tranforms the <a> tag to lowercase, the actual href value remains as it was originally entered ..

Comment: I tried this code in your example and I show in lowercase ¿?¿? :P